# Rails 3 error: Object doesn't support #inspect on includes (left outer join)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.

I have 3 models:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes, :class_name => "Wish"
  has_many :wishers, :through => :wishes, :source => :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes, :class_name => "Wish", :conditions => { 'wishes.wished' => true }
  has_many :wished_deals, :through => :wishes, :source => :deal
end

class Wish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :deal
end
```

And i'm trying to create the following scope in the Deal model:

```
scope :not_wished_by_user, lambda { |user| includes(:wishes).where('wishes.wished' != true, 'wishes.user_id' => user) }
```

What i want is all the Deals, except those that are marked as 'wished' by the given user in the block. But whenever i do that includes, i get the following error:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head > u = User.all.first
ruby-1.9.2-head > Deal.not_wished_by_user(u)
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
 =>
```

Also, placing it in a function doesn't work. Any idea what this could be?

Thanks!

EDIT: These are Wishes table migration

```
class CreateWish < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :wishes do |t|
      t.integer :deal_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.boolean :wished, :default => true
      t.boolean :collected, :default => false
      t.datetime :collected_date
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :wishes, [:deal_id, :user_id], :uniq => true
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure if this solves your problem, but this syntax is incorrect: `.where('wishes.wished' != true`. It should be `.where('wishes.wished' => false`.

Comment: Describe fields in database table Wishes

Comment: Oh thanks @mischa
Anyway, that didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Update below `vv`

### Old answer

You are not using any `Deal` attributes for selects so try to move code into `Wish` class:

```
class Wish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :deal

  scope :'wished?', lambda{ |f| where('wished = ?', f) }

  scope :not_wished_by_user, lambda{|user| wished?(false).where('user_id = ?', user)}
end
```

Usage exmple and output:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > Wish.not_wished_by_user(User.first).to_sql
  => "SELECT \"wishes\".* FROM \"wishes\" WHERE (wished = 't') AND (user_id = 1)"
```

Is this correct result for you?

PS:

In the `Deal` you can leave proxy-method like:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes, :class_name => "Wish"
  has_many :wishers, :through => :wishes, :source => :user

  def self.not_wished_by_user(user)
    Wish.not_wished_by_user(user)
  end
end
```

### Update1 (subquery)

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes, :class_name => "Wish"
  has_many :wishers, :through => :wishes, :source => :user

  scope :deal_ids_not_wished_by_user, lambda { |user|
    joins(:wishes).where('wishes.user_id = ?', user).where('wishes.wished = ?', false).select('deals.id')
  }

  scope :wished_by_user, lambda { |user|
    where("id not in (#{Deal.deal_ids_not_wished_by_user(user).to_sql})")
  }
end
```

Usage example and output:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > Deal.wished_by_user(User.first).to_sql
  => "SELECT \"deals\".* FROM \"deals\" WHERE (id not in (SELECT deals.id FROM \"deals\" INNER JOIN \"wishes\" ON \"wishes\".\"deal_id\" = \"deals\".\"id\" WHERE (wishes.user_id = 1) AND (wishes.wished = 'f')))"
```

### UPD2 (railish outer join)

Deal class:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes, :class_name => "Wish"
  has_many :wishers, :through => :wishes, :source => :user

  scope :not_wished_excluded, lambda { |user|
    joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN wishes on wishes.deal_id = deals.id').
      where('wishes.user_id = ? OR wishes.user_id is null', user).
      where('wishes.wished = ? OR wishes.wished is null', true)
  }
end
```

Usage:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :096 > Deal.not_wished_excluded(User.first).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"deals\".* FROM \"deals\" LEFT OUTER JOIN wishes on wishes.deal_id = deals.id WHERE (wishes.user_id = 1 OR wishes.user_id is null) AND (wishes.wished = 't' OR wishes.wished is null)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This isn't what i want. The problem is that this will give me just the Wishes objects that the user doesn't want , but what i want is exclude the Deal objects that the user doesn't want but not necessarily have a Wish object associated yet. That's why i'm doing an outer left join, an inner join won't make it because it will exclude all the deals that doesn't have yet a Wish object associated.

Comment: Updated answer with subquery variant. Is this what you need?